# Command to delete specific named files in a folder and sub-folder

Tags: bash, sed

I have a folder, named Octave, in my Documents folder and in this Octave folder there are numerous other sub-folders which contain SED scripts to delete certain files contained in these sub-folders. Is there a top level command I can run in the terminal that will run all these "delete" SED files in the sub-folders at once, or sequentially? I wish to do this to clean up the Octave folder prior to backing it up.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work (not tested):

```
for file in $(find $(pwd) -name "*.sed"); do
  cd $(basename $file);
  $file
done
```

Comment: Since your suggestion is not tested, could you perhaps explain what these commands do?

Comment: in a loop: 1) go to the directory of the sed file 2) execute it.

Comment: doesn't bash support $PWD ? Save a process, save a tree ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

What about find -exec command? Something like:

```
find /home/babelproofreader/Documents/Octave -type f -name "*.sed" -exec {} \;
```